# Rails object based permission/authorization engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, authorization

I want to add "Sharing documents" feature to my app, like in google documents service. As i see:

User can:

- can list/view/create/edit/delete own documents
- share own document to everyone - its a public document
- share own document to another user with read-only access
- share own document to another user with read-write access
- view list of own documents and users to whom he gave permission to read and write
- view list of foreign documents
- view/edit foreign document with read/write permissions

Please tell me, which permission/authorization solution is preffered for my task?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at some authorization plugins available here:

http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html

As for object level authorization/permission, it looks like [canable](http://github.com/jnunemaker/canable) can do this:

http://github.com/jnunemaker/canable

From the example in the readme:

```
class Article
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include Canable::Ables
  userstamps! # adds creator and updater

  def updatable_by?(user)
    creator == user
  end

  def destroyable_by?(user)
    updatable_by?(user)
  end
end
```

You could also define a viewable_by? method. You would still need some kind of permission fields or association on the document model, but after that you could use canable to simplify authorization in your controller/views.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I searched there already. And see all Ryan authorization related videos. cancan (and acl9 and declarative_authorization) can not satisfy my needs.

Comment: I updated my comment to focus on canable, since it seems like from the readme it can help you with per object authorization.

Comment: The best library I've found for object based permissions is called sanction, which unfortunately was never packaged as a gem and may be have gathered some cruft. https://github.com/matthewvermaak/sanction